# Querying featureLayer using date field and ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, feature-layer, date

I can query a featureLayer in my javascript map to only show features meeting criteria for normal attributes (strings/integers), as below for example

```
featurelayer.setDefinitionExpression("status = 0"); // working fine
```

However i would like to query based on date field in my feature layer -  (e.g. only display records newer than 01/01/2014)

in the service metadata the field is described as:

```
date_created ( type: esriFieldTypeDate , alias: DATE_CREATED , length: 36 )
```

I have looked through the the [documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html), however i have seen no mention of how to do this kind of query, the closest thing mentioned is the setTimeDefinition, but this appears more related to making time-aware maps rather than performing a simple filter on a layer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would set the expression as MYDATE >= date'1-16-2013' (date format may vary based on locale)

Example date range filter :

```
featurelayer.setDefinitionExpression("MYDATE >= date'1-16-2013' AND MYDATE < date'1/29/2015'")
```

Comment: thank you, this solved my issue! i did not know the the date'...' was necessary, but now it makes sense, cheers!